# Setting ng-model in nested ng-repeat to params for making ajax call

Tags: angularjs

Now I want a make an ajax call with ng-model values as params? How do I do that?
I am setting ng-model to json data which is a value. Everything is working fine. Am I allow to do that? How to set the scope for ng-model in controller?

**Controller**

```
EZlearn.controller("testController", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.test="false";
alert($scope.questions);
$scope.startTest = function(){  
    alert("starttest");
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'startTest'
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        $scope.questions  = data;
        alert($scope.questions);
        if($scope.questions!=""){
            $scope.test="true"
            //window.location.href="welcome.jsp";
        }
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        alert("");
    });
}  })
```

**Html**

```
<div data-ng-show="test" class="row">
    <form class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8" action="evaluateTest" method="post">
        <div data-ng-repeat="qus in questions" data-ng-init="value=$index+1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{value}}. {{qus.question}}</label>  
                <div data-ng-if="qus.questionType=='Radio'">
                    <div data-ng-repeat="options in qus.options">
                        <input type="radio" name="answer{{value}}" data-ng-model="qus.questionNumber" value="{{options}}" >{{options}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-ng-if="qus.questionType=='Text'">
                    <input type="text" name="answer{{value}}" data-ng-model="qus.questionNumber" >
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>  
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit Test" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
</div>
```

**Json Data**

```
{"questions":[  
{
    "questionNumber":"qus_one",
    "questionType":"Radio",
    "question":"What is HTML?", 
    "options":["Hyper text markup language","Hyper text makeup language"]
},  
{
    "questionNumber":"qus_two",
    "questionType":"Radio",
    "question":"What is XML?", 
    "options":["Extra markup language","Extended markup language"]
},  
{
    "questionNumber":"",
    "questionType":"Text",
    "question":"If X = (2+2), then What is the value of X?"
},
{
    "questionNumber":"qus_four",
    "questionType":"Radio",
    "question":"Which command is used to display the top of the file?", 
    "options":["cat","head","more","grep","None of the above"]
},
{
    "questionNumber":"qus_five",
    "questionType":"Radio",
    "question":"Which command is used to remove a directory?", 
    "options":["rd","rmdir","rdir","didir","None of the above"]
}  ]}
```

Comment: Please give more info. jsfiddle will be nice.

Comment: what data do you want to send ? The questions array is input or output of ajax call?

Comment: I want to send the respective radiobuttonvalue(which is a answer to the questions) as an input parameter to the http request.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context would allow a better answer, but I will generalize this the best I can.

To the best of knowledge, you can't call a function (where the ajax would live) with ng-model.  The point of ng-model is to set the value of a variable that is in the scope of the controller.  If you want to call a function with (what I guessing is a change in value, status, or state) you can achieve this with a $watch.

Have the watch function check the value of the variable that is set in ng-model and when it is changed the you can check the new value and do 'stuff' when the watch is triggered.  Here is a link to a watch example that you can use as a reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/

I'd recommend creating a scope variable and setting it to some arbitrary value, and pointing ng-model to your variable.  When the watch is hit you can check the newValue, if it's what you want/expect do your ajax request.

Further, depending on what UI framework/package you are using, there may be async functions you can call.  For example in Angular Material, the select (a dropdown element) you can set an attribute call md-on-open which will call a function (where you'd do the ajax request)

If this was not helpful, please provide a little more insight as to what you are doing and what elements you are using.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for sending as traditional GET request parameters):

```
    $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '--your url ---',
    params: $scope.questions

    ).then(function(res){
        //success callback
   }, function(res){
     //failure callback
    });
```

or use **data** in place of **params** if you want to specify POST request body.

```
    $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '--your url ---',
    data: $scope.questions

    ).then(function(res){
        //success callback
   }, function(res){
     //failure callback
    });
```

Of course, replace $scope.questions with your desired array if that was not intended to be sent. Take care what you send is an *object*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to take care that if you have angular 1.5.9, in this version `$hhtp.sucess` function is deprecated so its better to use `$http.then` function..

Now turning to your question i think there is one mistake ,our `data` is `object` and `data.question` is `array` which you need to pass `ng-repeat` see below

<----------Here is your Controller------->

```
EZlearn.controller("testController", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.test="false";
alert($scope.questions);
$scope.startTest = function(){  
    alert("starttest");
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'startTest'
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
//        $scope.questions  = data; //     <======== Here is problem 
        $scope.questions  = data.questions; //DO this instead 
        alert($scope.questions);
        if($scope.questions!=""){
            $scope.test="true"
            //window.location.href="welcome.jsp";
        }
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        alert("");
    });
}  })
```

<-----Html-->

```
<div data-ng-show="test" class="row">
    <form class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8" action="evaluateTest" method="post"> 

        <div data-ng-repeat="qus in questions" data-ng-init="value=$index+1">
            <div class="form-group">
                        <label>{{value}}. {{qus.question}}</label>  
            <div data-ng-if="qus.questionType=='Radio'">
                <div data-ng-repeat="options in qus.options">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer{{value}}" data-ng-model="qus.questionNumber" value="{{options}}" >{{options}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-ng-if="qus.questionType=='Text'">
                    <input type="text" name="answer{{value}}" data-ng-model="qus.questionNumber" >
            </div>  
            </div>
        </div>  
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit Test" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think there is a misunderstanding. Actually by calling startTest() I am getting the data(Json) from backend and displaying it using ng-repeat and now i want to retrive the data which is selected(radio button) by the user.